# ¿Cómo hacer que un botón me muestre 100 botones?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

Quiero que en mi código al momento de presionar un botón me muestre 100 botones separados pero solo he logrado hacer que muestre uno

Este es el código:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Botones</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <button type="button" id="button">Botón</button>
    <button type="button" id="show">Start</button> 

    <script>
      $(function(){
        $('#show').click(function(){
          $('#button').toggle();
        });
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Los 100 botones ya existen o hay que crearlos dinamicamente?

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer un [`prepend`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) para insertar contenido. Voy a colocarle un `id` al `body` (solamente como ejemplo, puedes hacerlo en un `div` u otra etiqueta o colocarle estilos para cambiarlos de lugar, esto insertará al principio del `body`).

- Cuando hagamos clic en el botón con `id` -> `show:

  - Con un bucle, por ejemplo hacemos un `prepend` o inserción de una línea HTML de ejemplo, esto añadirá 10 veces el contenido del `prepend` dentro de la etiqueta donde el atributo sea `test`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#show').click(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      $('#test').prepend('<button type="button" id="button">Botón</button>');
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Botones</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="test">
  <button type="button" id="button">Botón</button>
  <button type="button" id="show">Start</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No necesitas ID en el cuerpo, puedes acceder con `$(body)` y, definitivamente, no es buena idea que todos los botones tengan mismo ID. Referencia: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: Sí, efectivamente estás en lo cierto. Igual puede utilizar el contador del bucle para renombrar los IDs o usar la etiqueta. Pero es solamente un ejemplo. Gracias.